# How do you get a tkinter scale to have decimal values and lock to a base value

Tags: python, tkinter, slider

I'm trying to get a scale in tkinter to change values for an image's contrast. However, the lowest value is 0 and the highest value is 50 with the base value being one. Is there away to get the scale to start at 1 and have an equal distance to 0 and 50?

Comment: Tkinter doesn't have a slider widget. Do you mean the `Scale` widget? If so, this question can be answered by reading the documentation. What about the documentation don't you understand?

Comment: How am i supposed to get a "non-linear" scale? I want 1 to be in the center and 0 and 50 to be on the ends equally apart. However 50 is farther away from 1 than 0 so is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: Non-linear? I apologize, I didn't realize that's what you were asking. No, tkinter doesn't have anything like a non-linear scale.